# Storing names and grades in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm writing a program for A teacher. The teacher is suppose to ask the name of the student and then the grade of the student. And this for as many that is needed and then once the teacher enters 'q' the program is suppose to print out all the names and grades of the students in one on top of the other order. Here is what I have so far. the problem is Its not printing all the names and grades I'm trying to see how to store the names and grades together in a list of some sort. But I don,t know how.

```
while True:
    students = raw_input("Please give me the name of the student (q to quit): ")
    if students == 'q':
        break
    grade = raw_input("Please give me their grade: ")

print "Okay, printing grades!"
print "Student  Grade"
print students, grade
```

Comment: Do you need to persist this to disk? Or just print out names and grades at the end of the program?

Comment: You need to store the students into a list or a dict, currently you're overwriting the value of the `students` variable with the new one on every loop. I recommend reading some basic tutorials first, here's one for lists: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: i just need to print out the names and grades once they hit the break call

Comment: What if a student is called 'q'?

Comment: What this does is wait until the user hits `"q"`, then prints `"q"`, a space, then whatever the last entered grade was, or an error if `grade` hasn't been specified yet.

Comment: I was seeing about creating an empty list but i need what ever the teacher writes to be stored. Do i use the append() method. I am new to writing as you can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list of dictionaries. This will allow you to preserve the order in which they were entered.

```
students_grades = []

while True:
    data = {}
    data["student_name"] = raw_input("Please give me the name of the student (q to quit): ")
    if data["student_name"] == 'q':
        break
    data["grade"] = raw_input("Please give me their grade: ").capitalize()
    students_grades.append(data)

print "Okay, printing grades!"

for data in students_grades:
    print "{student_name}: {grade}".format(**data)
```

The `format` method on strings allows you to replace brackets in strings in various ways, one of which allows you to pass in kwargs that replace the corresponding named brackets. The splat operator `**` basically takes a dictionary and turns it into function kwargs, so it's the equivalent of passing in `.format(student_name="...", grade="...")` in this case.

Comment: This worked Julien Thank you very much I appreciate your intellect. I'm happy to I joined the online community in stack over flow.

Comment: Glad I could help Matias :)

Comment: And The **data method you used is a   **kwargs  function right to send the key and values to the list

Comment: Thanks again Julien thanks for taking the time to explain it. =+)

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy, using two arrays, zipping them to get a list of tuples and then subscripting the tuple:

```
students=[]
grades=[]
while True:
   student = raw_input("Please give me the name of the student (q to quit): ")
   if student == 'q':
       for i in zip(students, grades):
           print "Student: " + i[0] + ", Grade: " + i[1]
       break
   grade = raw_input("Please give me their grade: ")
   students.append(student)
   grades.append(grade)
```

Or without the `zip()`:

```
students=[]
grades=[]
while True:
   student = raw_input("Please give me the name of the student (q to quit): ")
   if student == 'q':  
       for i in range(len(students)):
           print "Student: " + students[i] + ", Grade: " + grades[i]
       break
   grade = raw_input("Please give me their grade: ")
   students.append(student)
   grades.append(grade)
```

---

#### Documentation

These is documentation related to this program:

- **[`zip()` in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)**
- **[Lists in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#)**
- **[`list.append()` in Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Using zip seems unnecessarily complicated for a beginner, when it's just as easily avoided. You fixed the error pointed out by @Jerfov2 though. +1.